# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: hadoop, twitter

I am trying to stream real time twitter data into HDFS using Apache flume. And when i run the command

```
./flume-ng agent -c /usr/local/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/ -f /usr/local/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/conf/flume.conf -n TwitterAgent
```

it gives me a SLF4j exception

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
```

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/etc/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Itdoes not allow the  program to run further.

[image: find the attached screenshot of the error here]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.